# MongoDB Query to remove specific objects from an array based on object keyword

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to remove several hundred thousand array objects spread out over thousands of documents that were migrated in error but can't quite get my query to work. I need to remove the entire array object if a single field within that object matches. Here's sample data:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5f11d4c28663f32e940696e0"
    },
    "Widgets": [{
        "WidgetId": 1,
        "Name": "Basic Widget",
        "YearLaunched": 2011,
        "InitialProduction": 50000,
        "WidgetIdLegacy": "leg-0120"
    }, {
        "WidgetId": 2,
        "Name": "Advanced Widget",
        "YearLaunched": 2013,
        "InitialProduction": 35000,
        "WidgetIdLegacy": "leg-0150"
    }, {
        "WidgetId": 3,
        "Name": "Prototype Widget",
        "YearLaunched": 2009,
        "InitialProduction": 100,
        "WidgetIdLegacy": "ptp-0004"
    }],
    "Manufacturer": "WidgetCo",
    "Status": 3,
}
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5f11d4c28663f32e940696e1"
    },
    "Widgets": [{
        "WidgetId": 10,
        "Name": "Widget 2.0",
        "YearLaunched": 2017,
        "InitialProduction": 150000,
        "WidgetIdLegacy": "leg-5099"
    }, {
        "WidgetId": 20,
        "Name": "Advanced Widget 2.0",
        "YearLaunched": 2018,
        "InitialProduction": 10000,
        "WidgetIdLegacy": "leg-5199"
    }, {
        "WidgetId": 3,
        "Name": "Prototype Widget",
        "YearLaunched": 2009,
        "InitialProduction": 100,
        "WidgetIdLegacy": "ptp-0004"
    }],
    "Manufacturer": "Acme Widgets",
    "Status": 3,
}
```

I want to remove the entire object from the Widgets array where the Widgets.WidgetIdLegacy: "ptp-0004".

Through reading other similar questions I write the following query which seems to find the objects but doesn't pull them so I know I'm missing something simple and fundamental

```
db.getCollection("sandbox.sample").update({},{$pull: {"WidgetIdLegacy": "ptp-0004"}},{multi:true});
```

The final data should look like:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5f11d4c28663f32e940696e0"
    },
    "Widgets": [{
        "WidgetId": 1,
        "Name": "Basic Widget",
        "YearLaunched": 2011,
        "InitialProduction": 50000,
        "WidgetIdLegacy": "leg-0120"
    }, {
        "WidgetId": 2,
        "Name": "Advanced Widget",
        "YearLaunched": 2013,
        "InitialProduction": 35000,
        "WidgetIdLegacy": "leg-0150"
    }],
    "Manufacturer": "WidgetCo",
    "Status": 3,
}
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5f11d4c28663f32e940696e0"
    },
    "Widgets": [{
        "WidgetId": 10,
        "Name": "Widget 2.0",
        "YearLaunched": 2017,
        "InitialProduction": 150000,
        "WidgetIdLegacy": "leg-5099"
    }, {
        "WidgetId": 20,
        "Name": "Advanced Widget 2.0",
        "YearLaunched": 2018,
        "InitialProduction": 10000,
        "WidgetIdLegacy": "leg-5199"
    }],
    "Manufacturer": "Acme Widgets",
    "Status": 3,
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `$pullAll` will not work for this try this `db.getCollection("sandbox.sample").update({},{$pull: {"Widgets": {"WidgetIdLegacy": "ptp-0004"}}},{multi:true});`

Comment: I pasted the wrong query in and you're right, $pullAll doesn't work, but $pull only finds the array objects, it's not removing them as expected. I've made the appropriate edit to my question. Thank you!

Comment: read again my first comment.. its solution.

Comment: Ah! Yes, I see it now, thank you! I'll post the answer, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working solution!

```
db.getCollection("sandbox.sample").update({},{$pull: {"Widgets": {"WidgetIdLegacy": "ptp-0004"}}},{multi:true});
```

I needed to define the name of the array first, that was the missing component

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [`$pull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) operator to remove the sub-document.

```
var filter = Object.create(null);

var update = {
    $pull: {
        Widgets: {
            WidgetIdLegacy: "ptp-0004"
        }
    }
};

var options = { 
    multi: true 
};

db.collection.update(filter, update, options);
```